# Keeping VIM marks/folds even if code is edited/line numbers change

Tags: git, vim

So, as marks and folds are saved based on line number in vim, when someone else has edited the code in a way that changes the line numbering, my marks/folds are misplaced.

Example:

my original code

```
1 | # do something            |
2 |                           |
3 | def foo():                | <- here I place my mark
4 |     print("hello world!") |
```

someone else edits the code, so when I pull down the changes it looks like this

```
1 | # do something            |
2 | # do something else       | <- added by another user
3 |                           | <- now my mark is here (still on line 3)
4 | def foo():                | <- I want my mark to be moved down here automatically
5 |     print("hello world!") |
```

Does anyone know a fix for this? Note that I am the only one using vim in my team, so a shared viminfo file is not an option.

Comment: This might be doable with text properties. But if you’re marking functions, have a look at universal ctags

Answer (score 0):

On my vim the mark keeps its string relates to the original position. Could you please test with:

```
 vim -u NONE
```

The above line leads vim with no config file

Comment: hmm, I am setting my viminfo path in my vimrc, so when loading vim without a vimrc I get no marks whatsoever.